# How to Serialize BigIntegerField, TextField in serializer Django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, textfield, biginteger

I have a model which has following attributes

```
from django.db import models
class ApiLogs(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    user_agent = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    client_version = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    token = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    uri = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I have defined a serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class ApiSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user_id = serializers.BigIntegerField( allow_null=True)
    ip = serializers.CharField(max_length=16)
    user_agent = serializers.TextField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
    client = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
    client_version = serializers.CharField(max_length=50, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
    token = serializers.TextField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
    uri = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    method = serializers.CharField(max_length=20)
```

But it is showing error somewhat like this

```
user_id = serializers.BigIntegerField( allow_null=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BigIntegerField'
```

for textfield

```
user_agent = serializers.TextField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextField'
```

Now how to serialize this type of data.

Comment: what are your imports?

Comment: @e4c5 I have included the imports.

Comment: `serializers.CharField(max_length=None)` is somewhat equivalent to `model.TextField()`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is because the django rest framework's [Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializer-fields) doesn't have a TextField. Where your model has a TextField you need to use a CharField in the serializer.

> CharField A text representation. Optionally validates the text to be
>   shorter than max_length and longer than min_length.
>
> Corresponds to `django.db.models.fields.CharField` or
>   `django.db.models.fields.TextField`.

The documentation isn't as clear about `BigIntegerFields` from models, but this [line for the source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d2994e0596c3163ac970b29dad6a61485f938045/rest_framework/serializers.py#L841) shows that IntegerField is again what you have to use in the serializer.

Comment: For those looking at this answer, the updated link (08 Mar 2018) for the relevant source code is [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d2994e0596c3163ac970b29dad6a61485f938045/rest_framework/serializers.py#L841)

Answer (score 5):

For text field you can follow the following convention

`your_variable_name = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})`

Suggested in rest framework documentation.

Comment: What different between CharField() with no defined max_length  and CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'}) in serializer?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `TextField` with `CharField`. Both have basically the same functionality, but serializers understand only the later.